# Why are all observations outside confidence intervals considered outliers?

Tags: confidence-interval

The theory of boxplots is that we can find outliers by identifying the points that are outside the confidence intervals.

In general, do statisticians consider points that are outside the confidence intervals of the mean to be considered noise?

Comment: I'm not aware of a 'theory of boxplots'. The *whiskers* of a boxplot do not constitute a confidence interval. The idea to explore points beyond 1.5*IQR + 3rd quartile, eg, as potential outliers is a heuristic, not a rule or law.

Comment: No. I think that's just terminology to describe points on a boxplot.

Comment: The theoretical nature of box plots assumes that: all points that are outside the fences, are outliers. Should this theory be taken seriously?

Comment: As gung et. al states, this is a heuristic; interesting.

Comment: Statisticians do not compare individual values to CIs of the mean, because such a comparison is meaningless as well as useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not noise, definitely. Outliers, possibly, depending on how you define them. 
In any case, it depends on the underlying phenomenon. If it is very skewed, then it's not unexpected that some observations will lie beyond the whiskers.

There are very good sources around, such as this clear statement from [Dawson](http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v19n2/dawson.pdf):

> It is common to consider Tukey’s schematic (“full”) boxplot as an
>   informal test for the existence of outliers.  While the procedure  is
>   useful, it should be used with caution, as at least 30% of samples
>   from a  normally-distributed population  of any size will be flagged
>   as containing an outlier, while for small samples (N<10) even extreme
>   outliers indicate little.

Other key insights can be found, for instance, in [Tukey's bio](http://mnstats.morris.umn.edu/introstat/history/w98/Tukey.html) and in a historical piece by [Wickham and Stryjewski](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/boxplots.pdf).